# Expander arrow on /editing-help is way too close to the text!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editing-help

As you can see in this image, the little arrow used to show you can expand the section (on [the markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)) is too close to the text:

[image]

Can it be moved a bit to the right?

It can be done easily by adding a `margin-left: 2px;` (2px for example) to the `expander-arrow-small-hide` class:

[image]

But I don't know if that has any unintended side-effects elsewhere on the site, although it is a much simpler solution than manually adding `&nbsp;` to every single one (on every single site...)!

---

As an aside: There's quite a bit of useless white-space between the header and `Code and Preformatted Text` - any reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented in build 3759 on MSE/MSO, and build 2880 on other sites.